# Set FILE by concatenating string and variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me to understand why FILE cannot be set as shown below -

```
DECLARE @name varchar(100)
DECLARE @db varchar(50)
SET @db = N'Adventure'
SET @name = @db + '_bak' --okay, allowed
SELECT @name
RESTORE DATABASE [@db] 
FILE = @db + '_bak' -- NOT allowed
--mode code to be added
```

I know that I can set `FILE` with a variable, but I don't want to create a variable 
just for that. How do I set `FILE` directly ?

Comment: Are you receiving an error?

Comment: You shouldn't have to create a new variable because you already have that value available. Is there a reason you cannot use "@name" there? Or are you trying to avoid declaring/using "@name"?

Comment: @b.runyon - trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just like that: You cannot use *expressions* as freely in SQL as in a programming language, especially not for a function parameter.

You'll have to use a *constant expression* here, either a string or a variable.